# Identifying host and network ID

Tags: networking, ip-address

I have a question. I was doing some networking quiz and I stumbled upon these two questions and I have no idea why these are the correct answers.

---

Question 1: An IPv4 address is given as `177.132.25.19/24`. What are the network ID and host ID of the recipient?

The answer to this question was `Network ID: 177.132.25 Host ID: 19` instead of `Network ID: 177.132 Host ID; 25.19`. From what I understood from the classes, is that you need to look at the first decimal (so in this case 177) and check what class it belongs to. So 177 would be class B right? And if it's class B, network ID should be two first decimals and host ID last two decimals? What am I missing here?

---

Question 2: is `145.34.12.44/24` on the same network as `145.34.15.10/24`?

The answer was no. But again, 145 falls in class B, which means two first decimals should the network ID, so that should mean that these two addresses are on the same network?

---

Could someone help me understand why the answers to these questions are correct?

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains all of that.

Comment: "_From what I understood from the classes, is that you need to look at the first decimal (so in this case 177) and check what class it belongs to. So 177 would be class B right?_" No! Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (two years before the commercial Internet!) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). We have not used network classes in this century.